# Setting up Linux FTP

Tags: linux, ftp

I have a Linux webserver (CentOS) and I wish to set up FTP access to the server. According to the IP table port 21 is open and connections to it are accepted but I'm not sure what to do now.

How do I go about setting up FTP users and enabling in on the Linux install?

Comment: this does not belong here.

Comment: This is entirely specific to the FTP server you are using (which you fail to mention), and almost definitely is well documented by the author(s).

Comment: @ChrisDown I do mention what type of server I am using (CentOS), and I'm sure it is well documented if you hadn't only started looking at Linux 3 days ago. I don't konw what I am looking for, which is why I am asking for help. If you don't have anything useful to add, please refrain from commenting - I already know I'm thick, you don't need to try and point that out.

Comment: CentOS is *not* the FTP server, it is the Linux distribution you are using. Start by looking at `man [your ftp server]`. I haven't made any comment saying that you're "thick", despite your claims to the contrary, please refrain from putting words in my mouth.

Comment: I remember when this community used to be a question and answer site and not a "go RTFM, n00b!" site.

Comment: @AaronCopley - If I had known which manual to read then I certainly would have. Surely one of the valuable functions of sites like this is to help n00b's like me? I'm sure at some point in your career you would certainly have asked questions that you now consider stupid. Likewise, I'm sure that there are subjects that you are still trying to learn, I just hope people are a little more sympathetic to your novice status than you were to mine.

Comment: @ChrisDown - My point (which you obviously missed) is that I didn't know. All I was after was a post like those below, somthing to point me in the right direction. So instead of saying "which you fail to mention", how about making a suggestion as to how I could have found that information out?

Comment: @DavidGard, I'm with you not against you. :) That comment was lamenting how people didn't used to gripe at every question posted -- they helped!

Comment: @AaronCopley - Apologies, I misinterpreted you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that out of the box CentOS has vsftpd installed. You can check this with

```
rpm -qa | grep ftpd
vsftpd-2.2.2-6.el6_0.1.x86_64
```

If it's not installed you can install it with

```
yum install vsftpd
```

Once installed you can start and stop it with the service command

```
service vsftpd start 
Starting vsftpd for vsftpd:                              [  OK  ]
```

or

```
service vsftpd stop
Shutting down vsftpd:                                     [  OK  ]
```

That's the basics, the rest involves reading the vsftpd and vsftpd.conf man pages.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. As explained above I'm new to this so I had no idea what to look for. I've now managed to get it installed and working (ish), hopefully I'll be able to tweek it to exactly as I want it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the RHEL6 documentation for how to set up an FTP server using vsftp.  This assumes you're using CentOS6.  If not, there should be a corresponding piece of documentation for the specific release of RHEL/CentOS:

http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-FTP.html

Comment: Sure.  That should be where you can look for the "official" documentation for CentOS/RHEL.  Whatever documentation CentOS has will basically be a copy of what RHEL publishes.